# I have experience in writing texts for XYZ, and I was responsible for

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can you say this way?

> I have experience in writing texts for XYZ, ***and*** I was responsible for
> ...

I just want to make a smooth transition between my past experience and the things I did so I was wondering whether the word "and" works here or not.

Comment: I sure hope whomever your audiences is understands what you have done. It's not clear from the outside; I came away with the impression that this was a resume` sentence about writing text messages.

Answer (score 1):

If the things you were responsible for were part of writing texts for XYZ, then "and” works here.

Another way to do this is to end the first part of the sentence, and start new sentence with "Specifically, I was responsible for..."